# Cached images when using cordova image picker includes "%"

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to process images from my gallery using the cordova imagepicker plugin.  Here is my code:

```
    $scope.getProductImage = function() {       
        // Image picker will load images according to these settings
        var options = {
            maximumImagesCount: 1, // Max number of selected images, I'm using only one for this example
            quality: 80            // Higher is better
        };

        $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options).then(function (imageData) {
            // Loop through acquired images
            for (var i = 0; i < imageData.length; i++) {
                $scope.sourceDirectory = imageData[i].substring(0, imageData[i].lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                $scope.sourceFileName = imageData[i].substring(imageData[i].lastIndexOf('/') + 1, imageData[i].length);
                $scope.fileName = $scope.sourceDirectory + $scope.sourceFileName
            }
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            // In case of error
        });
    };
```

However, some images return a $scope.sourceFileName that contains a "%".  This causes the moveFile in the cordova file plugin to fail with error code 1.  Other images that does not contain the "%" is being processed correctly.  Any ideas on why this is?

Comment: usually the `%` characters is used when "escaping" other characters. For example, in some queries, the space is represented with a `%20`. So maybe it tries to match something with that `%`, that is not there. I don't know cordova,by the way, this is just a suggestion about what to look into.

Comment: thanks.  you're right that the plugin replaced the space with %20 so I just replaced it back to space.

Comment: happy to have been of help :D

Answer (score 1):

turns out it's a space replaced by "%20".  I just did a string replace and it worked.